# Expensive GetComponent<CanvasGroup>() call, unsure how to cache

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting a performance warning from my IDE that the **GetComponent()** call is expensive, especially since I am calling **MoveCards()** in **Update()**. I understand why it's expensive and usually know how to fix with caching in **Awake()** but since it's prefixed with **cards[i]**, I am unsure how to go about it.

```cs
private void MoveCards()
        {
            // This loop moves the cards.
            for (var i = 0; i < cards.Length; i++)
            {
                cards[i].localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cards[i].localPosition, cardPositions[i + cardArrayOffset],
                    Time.deltaTime * cardMoveSpeed);
                if (!(Mathf.Abs(cards[i].localPosition.x - cardPositions[i + cardArrayOffset].x) < 0.01f)) continue;
                cards[i].localPosition = cardPositions[i + cardArrayOffset];

                // This disables interaction with cards that are not on top of the stack.
                cards[i].gameObject.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().interactable = cards[i].localPosition.x == 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could store references in a dictionary and grab the canvas group by the object. So you'd have a <GameObject, CanvasGroup>. To extend this functionality simply change CanvasGroup to a class and store multiple references within it. The class would just hold data and do nothing else. Also why do are you using a canvas group for one object? Do cards have more interactions than the card itself?

Comment: What type is `cards`?

Comment: @Ruzihm Transform[]

Comment: `cards[i].localPosition.x == 0` When comparing floats, it's better form to do an approximate comparison in the event of rounding errors.  `Mathf.Approximately(0f, cards[i].localPosition.x);`

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make the card GameObject have it’s own MonoBehaviour to store a reference to those components. Then, change the cards collection to store a reference to the card MonoBehaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You would store `cards[]` as a `CanvasGroup` instead of a `GameObject`.

You would declare it like this in `Awake()`:

```
 GameObject[] cardObjects = new GameObject[10];
 CanvasGroup[] cards = new CanvasGroup[cardObjects.Length];

 for (int i = 0; i < cardObjects.Length; i++)
 {
     cards[i] = cardObjects[i].GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
 }
```

We loop through all of the card objects, and assign that component to a certain object in an array.

In your function you showed in the question, you would change it to this:

```
private void MoveCards()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cardObjects.Length; i++)
    {
        cardObjects[i].transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cardObjects[i].transform.localPosition, cardPositions[i + cardArrayOffset], Time.deltaTime * cardMoveSpeed);
        if (!(Mathf.Abs(cardObjects[i].transform.localPosition.x - cardPositions[i + cardArrayOffset].x) < 0.01f)) continue;
            cardObjects[i].localPosition = cardPositions[i + cardArrayOffset]
            cards[i].interactable = cardObjects[i].transform.localPosition.x == 0;
        }
    }
```

We change all of the `cards` variables to `cardObjects`. On the `GetComponent<>()` line, we keep `cards` and remove the `.gameObject.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>()`.

**Important:** You didn’t show us where some of the variables were created. Like `cardPositions`. If this is created using `cards`, make sure to use the `cardObjects` variable.

Comment: I don’t think this is a great approach as it’s not very flexible if you were to require access to more components down the track. You’ll end up either refactoring it or making the code very messy.